# Redis "This instance has cluster support disabled" error?

Tags: redis, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using WSL. I installed Redis through `apt-get`, built it from source, and installed it from a PPA. In all 3 cases, I get `This instance has cluster support disabled`. I have `cluster-enabled yes` in the config file. I restarted everything. How do I enable cluster support?

Comment: Hi! Do you have any update on this? How did you resolved this? @Leo Jiang?

Answer (score 2):

I think in addition to setting `cluster-enabled` to `yes` you have to actually configure a cluster. See [the Redis cluster tutorial](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial), specifically the section "Creating the cluster"